# javascript - Custom URL Pattern

Tags: javascript, url-pattern

Get Values from URL

`var acutal_url = HTTP://my_host.com/account/apps/6/dashboard/6`;

what i want is

`var pattern_url = HTTP://my_host.com/account/apps/<int:app_id>/dashboard/<int:dash_id> ;`

I want `app_id & dash_id` separately from this URL ..

Is it possible using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var acutal_url = "HTTP://my_host.com/account/apps/6/dashboard/6"
var app_id = acutal_url.substring( acutal_url.indexOf("/apps/") + 6, acutal_url.indexOf("/dashboard/") ); 

var dash_id = acutal_url.substring( acutal_url.indexOf("/dashboard/") + 11 );  
alert(app_id);
alert(dash_id);
```

Comment: Great Thanks ! it works ...!

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions, but just in case you want a tool to do it for you, try http://txt2re.com/